# Angular 4 lifecycle hook for template rendering

Tags: jquery, angular, zurb-foundation

I'm developing an Angular 4 application using the Foundation 6 framework for styling and UI. Among others, I'm using its 'Tabs' element to display several pages of information on the same div. To make it work, the application must run `$(document).foundation()` to initialize all the stuff needed. The problem is that, on start, the component where I use the 'Tabs' element is hidden using a `*ngIf` directive, and it's only shown when the user selects an object identifier from a list.
To try to fix it, when the user selects an object ID and the component is loaded, I run the following code when I get the results from the DB:

```
$(function() {
  $('#tabbed_element').foundation();
  $('#tabbed_element').foundation('selectTab', 'objectTab');
});
```

This solution has the following drawbacks:

- As the code is ran everytime I click on an object, I call multiple times to the foundation function, getting this warning from the second time:

  Tried to initialize tabs on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.
- In theory, running the 'selectTab' function should select the wanted tab ('objectTab' in this case) and it does BUT the first time that the 'Tabs' element is shown I can see the tabs on the left (it's a vertical tab) but nothing on the right, where the data should be. Selecting another tab makes it work perfectly.
- Everything runs fine until I hide the object panel. When I do this and double click on an object id again, I have the same trouble (no data shown).

I've tried to run the code in all the Angular lifecycle hooks (such as ngAfterViewInit, ngAfterContentInit etc) but I couldn't get it working.

I'm quite sure that the problem comes from the fact that I call the foundation function when the DOM isn't fully loaded (perhaps because the 'Tabs' element is inside a div with a '*ngIf' directive, only shown when the user selects an object). So, my question is, is there any hook being called when the component template is ready to show? This way, I would initialize foundation from it instead of when I get the data from the DB.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the 'ngAfterViewChecked' hook like this:

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  // Check if the DOM has an element with template name 'item_panel_tabs' (obtained through ViewChild on the component's beginning)
  if (this.itemTabsElement) {
    // If the element exists, check if we have initialized it (this is done by running the foundation() function on the element)
    if(!this.tabsInit) {
      // If not, 1) call Foundation function
      $(this.itemTabsElement.nativeElement).foundation();

      // 2) Change to the 'objectPanel' tab
      $(this.itemTabsElement.nativeElement).foundation('selectTab', 'objectPanel');

      // And 3) Mark the component as initialized
      this.tabsInit = true;
    }
  }
  else {
    // If the element doesn't exist in the DOM, mark it as uninitialized
    this.tabsInit = false;
  }
}
```

In the component code:

```
@ViewChild('item_panel_tabs') itemTabsElement : ElementRef;
private tabsInit : boolean = false;
```

In the HTML template:

```
<ul class="vertical tabs" data-tabs id="item-panel-tabs" #item_panel_tabs>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#objectPanel"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Object</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#infoPanel"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Info</a></li>
</ul>
```

Cheers,