# When does template start to be rendered in Angular?

Tags: angular

Angular doc says `ngAfterViewInit` called after view is fully rendered. But couldn't find when does Angular start to render template and when does it end ?
For example ;

```
 import { Component, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';



@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
 title = 'relation';
 name="Balbazar"

 constructor(private http:HttpClient){

 }
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
 }
 
 ngOnInit(){
   const div:any =  (document.querySelector(".hey") as any)
   console.log(div); // --> it prints element truely. Even innertext;

   const div:any =  (document.querySelector(".hey") as any).innerText;
   console.log(div); // --> innerText is not printed truely. It is printed empty string



 }
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {

 }
   
}
```

As mentioned above when I try to get **HTML element** in `ngOnInit` it gives me correct result. I think before `ngOnInit` the component's template is fully being rendered. But when try to get **innerText** of **HTML element** it gives empty string. If I use exact same code in `ngAfterViewInit`, **innerText** is printed truely as expected. Because Angular doc already says that. However, when is the exact time to start and end the template render process?

Comment: I *think* maybe you're looking for the appropriate Angular lifecycle hook: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks.  Perhaps `ngAfterViewChecked()` might work for you?  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47306015/421195

Comment: I really don't understand how is this helpful ? It just says  `ngAfterViewChecked` is called after `ngAfterViewInit` . But already knows that template was fully rendered after `ngAfterViewInit`. It says in doc. But doesn't say something about 
What is the start and end time of the render process of the component  @paulsm4

Comment: Q: Why exactly do you want to know "when Angular starts to render a template"?  Do you want to "do something" at "some point" in the rendering process?  Please clarify your goal.

Comment: Actually I asked because  I really want to build a healthy mental model how does angular really work and couldn't find any satisfying answer anywhere.  I know the deep I learn, the better and comfortable I use

Comment: The documented "lifecycle" is probably your best bet for understanding "what happens, and when".  I'd definitely encourage you to use the "spy" functionality to observe the "flow" in real time.